# Every holomorphic map between Kähler manifolds is harmonic

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I was reading the Wikipedia article on harmonic maps and saw the following statement in the 'examples' section:

> Every holomorphic map between Kähler manifolds is harmonic.

I am not that familiar with harmonic maps, so I haven't been able to figure out why this is true. A quick google search didn't provide me the answer either. Is there a simple explanation for why this is true? If not, does anyone know of a reference for this fact?

Comment: *Quick Google search* found this reference: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02924136‎

Comment: @njguliyev: I don't see how that immediately applies to my question.

Comment: It seems the relevant sentence is "On vérifie immédiatement que s'il en est aussi toute application preque holomorphe (out preque antiholomorphe) de $M$ dans $M'$ est harmonique." Not sure whether the preceding material justifies this "immediate verification" or if the author just considers it obvious.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1988-102-04/S0002-9939-1988-0934892-9/) it is said that "Lichnerowicz has proved that holomorphic maps between Kahler manifolds are harmonic with respect to the Kahler metrics [6]." The paper I linked above is this [6]. Sorry if this is not what you asked for.

Comment: Check out the first ~15 pages of http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0081912 if you can access it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking, here is a nice reference:
Calculus of variations and harmonic maps-By Hajime Urakawa, see chapter 4, proposition 3.14 (page 146). It is a very interesting book in general.

Answer (score 1):

An excellent reference for Kahler manifolds, maps, and specifically harmonic maps is James Eells and Luc Lemaire, "Two Reports on Harmonic Maps," which incidentally also contains a third report, published by World Scientific.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, I try to add a proof here

Let $F$, be a holomorphic map between compact Kahler manifolds $(M,J)$ and $(N,J')$, then $$\nabla F_*(X,JY)=\nabla_XF_*(JY)-F_*\nabla_X(JY)$$ but $$\nabla F_*(X,JY)=J'(\nabla F_*)(X,Y)$$

and $$\nabla F_*(JX,JY)=-\nabla F_*(X,Y)$$

Choose a local orthonormal frame $\{e_1,...,e_m,\bar{e_1},...,\bar{e_m}\}$ for $M$, such that $Je_i=\bar e_i$ for all $i$. Hence we obtain

$$\tau(F)=\sum_{i=1}^m(\nabla F_*)(e_i,e_i)+(\nabla F_*)(\bar e_i,\bar e_i)=0$$

The map $F$ is said to be harmonic if its tension field
vanishes i.e. $\tau (F) = 0$.

See [Riemannian Submersions, Riemannian Maps in Hermitian Geometry, and their ...
By Bayram Sahin](https://www.elsevier.com/books/riemannian-submersions-riemannian-maps-in-hermitian-geometry-and-their-applications/sahin/978-0-12-804391-2)